# Change arrow style in chemmacros 5.1

Tags: chemmacros

How can I change the arrowstyle etc.? The code below used to work pre v5.0. I've searched around the manual and the net a bit, but didn't really find something useful. Is it even possible in v5.1?

MnWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\chemsetup[chemformula]{arrow-style = {>=stealth',line cap=round,thick}}
\RenewChemArrow{->}{\draw[chemarrow,->] (cf_arrow_start) -- (cf_arrow_end) ;}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-spec = {[Numbers={Proportional,Lining}]MinionPro}}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{reactions}
  M (OR)_{$n$} + H2O                            &-> M (OR)_{$n-1$} OH + ROH                         \\
  (RO)_{$n'$}M-OH + HO-M(RO)_{$n'$} &-> (RO)_{$n'$}M-O-M(RO)_{$n'$} + H2O                   
\end{reactions}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to change a `chemformula` property, not a `chemmacros` one. Prior to v5.1 `chemmacros` just loaded `chemformula` so things worked. As of v5.1 `chemmacros` let's the user choose if he wants to use `chemformula` or `mhchem` for typing formulas and reactions, see section 6.2 *The chemformula Module* for details.

If the user doesn't make a choice then at the end of the preamble `chemformula` is loaded, anyway. However, this means that without making a choice `chemformula`'s options are not available in the preamble. (I am aware that this is not ideal…)

Possible solutions:

- load `\usepackage{chemmacros,chemformula}` and use `\setchemformula{}` instead of `\chemsetup[chemformula]{}`, or
- add `\chemsetup{ formula = chemformula }` before changing the arrows, or
- wait for the update to 5.2 and use `\usepackage[compatibility=5.0]{chemmacros}` (this *should* work already but doesn't because I didn't take care enough…)

PS: you can set multiple options with one call of `\chemsetup`:

```
\chemsetup[chemformula]{
  arrow-style = {>=stealth',line cap=round,thick} ,
  font-spec = {[Numbers={Proportional,Lining}]MinionPro}
}
```

PPS: if you just want to change the arrow tips of `chemformula`'s arrows you can simply set them:

```
\pgfkeys{
  cf/.tip = <tip> ,
  left cf/.tip = <tip> ,
  right cf/.tip = <tip>
}
```

see the TikZ-manual section 16.5 *Reference: Arrow Tips* for possible choices